# How to save an image to the clipboard only knowing the images path

Tags: c#, image, clipboard, bitmapsource

Say if I have an image path `C:\MyImages\MyImage.jpg` how would I get this onto the clipboard using C#.

I know I would use the class `System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage();`
but this takes a `BitmapSource` as the parameter. How would I get a `BitmapSource` object to feed into this method from the given path?

Comment: The question sited as a duplicate does not mentions how to put the image in the clipboard which is clearly part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BitmapSource bitmapSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\MyImages\\MyImage.jpg"));
System.Windows.Clipboard.SetImage(bitmapSource);
```